# Response form API and working with in php

Tags: php, web-services

I have a response from an API Web service and i want to get values this object.example : TimeStamp,TransactionID,SubscriptionResponse

and show this values different DIV in HTML code.
how to get this value and working with theme??

Response from API:

```
object(SubscriptionResponseContainer)#11 (5) { 
    ["Timestamp":protected]=> string(25) "2015-09-15T04:30:00+04:30"        
    ["TransactionId":protected]=> string(10) "1445756101" 
    ["SubscriptionResponse":protected]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(SubscriptionResponseItemCollection)#12 (2) {    
            ["Activate":protected]=> NULL 
            ["Renew":protected]=> NULL 
        } 
    } 
    ["SubscriptionError":protected]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(SubscriptionResponseErrorCollection)#13 (2) { 
            ["ActivateError":protected]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> object(ResponseItemErrorType)#14 (4) { 
                    ["UnitId":protected]=> int(1) 
                    ["SubscriberId":protected]=> string(11) "09394354387" 
                    ["ErrorCode":protected]=> int(1)   
                    ["ErrorMessage":protected]=> string(70) "SubscriberId specified in the activate order was previously activated." 
                } 
            } 
            ["RenewError":protected]=> NULL 
        } 
    } 
    ["TransactionError":protected]=> NULL 
}
```

Comment: Please put your API url and specify related callable method if it is possible to more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
$timestamp=$result['Timestamp'];
$TransactionID=$result['Timestamp']['TransactionID'];
```

Comment: no i try this and not working!without result!!

Comment: can you tell me that ur api url

Comment: no sorry!i Was banned!!thnx ;)

Comment: you get the error. protected means that only descendants of the Code class can access that property, you can handle it with $timestamp->timestamp or $result->gettimestamp()

Comment: Yes!!Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: ok.please accept this answer and plus it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93280/discussion-between-hessam-zaheri-and-fatemeh-namkhah).

Answer (score -1):

You can do: `$obj->Timestamp`

Or to convert into an array:

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

Comment: no working because Timestamp is protected

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access protected property SubscriptionResponseContainer::$Timestamp

Comment: have you tried get_object_vars?
please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: Yes but no result yet!